# Bash: display all instances of negative numbers as zero

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

After some math, I'd like to display all occurrences of negative numbers as zero instead.  Simple example:

```
num1=6
num2=8
firstresult=$(( $num1 - $num2 ))
echo $result
#
num3=2
num4=9
secondresult=$(( $num3 - $num4 ))
echo $secondresult
```

so on... both result variables will yield a negative number, obviously.  I'd like those numbers to display as zeros.

Maybe some function to write?  Not sure.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
no_negatives () {
    echo "$(( $1 < 0 ? 0 : $1 ))"
}
```

That's a pretty crummy name, feel free to pick a better one. Then:

```
$ a=5 b=3
$ no_negatives $((a - b))
2
$ no_negatives $((b - a))
0
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is exactly what I needed.  Wish I had more reputation to upvote you.